# Getting a column which shows above and below for each person based on the average value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query for " Display the EMPLOYEE_NAME, DEPARTMENT_NAME & a field that says “ABOVE” if his salary is above the average salary of all employees; “BELOW” is his salary is below average.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME,DEPARTMENT_ID

(CASE
WHEN (SALARY>=(SELECT AVG(SALARY)FROM HR.EMPLOYEES)) THEN 'ABOVE'
ELSE 'BELOW'
END) "SALARY STATUS"
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES;
```

But now I want to get the same result with field, saying above and below but based on average salary of all **employees in his department**. there are almost 14 department. I am stuck here, can please anybody help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME,DEPARTMENT_ID
    (CASE
        WHEN (SALARY>=(SELECT AVG(B.SALARY)FROM HR.EMPLOYEES AS B WHERE A.DEPARTMENT_ID = B.DEPARTMENT_ID))
        THEN 'ABOVE'
        ELSE 'BELOW'
    END)
"SALARY STATUS"
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES AS A;
```

Comment: Thanks Avt for response, when I try the above query, I keep getting missing right parenthesis error, however I am not missing any, any thoughts on this.

Comment: I made some small changes like I removed As from everywhere and now its working, Thanks for your help. I just have one think to ask, why didnt we mention about table HR.EMPLOYEES A under the case staatement.

Comment: Just a thought.. for every row in Employee table, `AVG()` is been calculated and compared again and again though the AVG salary of the department would have been calculated for the department previously.. !! So we do reduntant operations.. Higher the employee count, higher the rate of redundancy ...This is not acceptable in any RDBMS.. And this is why , we isolate the common component as an `View` and join the results finally!

Comment: @OracleUser, I agree logic is not ideal - I wrote "quick" solution. But you are not right! In modern RDBMS requests and results are cached! So if the same query is calculated and table was not modified we will receive cached results. So performance should not be very terrible.

Comment: @Utkarsh sahu, if you like my answer, please do not forget to vote up it ! :)

Comment: This is something our senior Architects advise us.. "Powerful Database makes bad queries works smart.. But does that mean, we always write un-optimised SQLs, and leave the DBMS to decide"

Comment: Not always :) only when we are limited by time and in non-critical places. I agree your query is better.